# Why Image tag doesn't accept # as src?

Tags: html, tags

Can someone explain why file names like this returns an error?

```
<img alt="" src="uploads/#hje-bubble-wrap-factory.jpeg">
```

Comment: it's special character so HTML doesn't accept it in property

Comment: Hi woninana, this question is missing some of the details we usually look for and might not be seen as high quality by the community. Without details like where else you've looked for information or the specific error you're getting, you're likely to get down votes and the question could be closed :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `src` property of an [`img` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) expects either an absolute or relative URL to a valid, supported image file. [URL syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax) defines  anything following the `#` to be a fragment identifier.

Thus, in your example only `uploads/` is considered the file path, while the `#hje-bubble-wrap-factory.jpeg` segment is parsed as a fragment identifier.

A fragment is a designated section within an HTML or XML document, so a browser will try to parse the URL path (`uploads/`) and then locate the fragment (`#hje-bubble-wrap-factory.jpeg`) within that file. However, since there isn't a file at `uploads/`, the HTTP response is likely HTML from the server (or nothing at all), which can't be displayed as an image ;)

If your file name actually contains a `#`, you can encode it, however using special characters isn't recommended for filenames.

Note though that a fragment identifier is perfectly valid within the `src` property. You can use that trick for all kinds of [fun things with SVGs](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/).

Answer (score 2):

The # (hash) character among others are characters that require special encoding for the url to be considered safe. The `img` html element requires the `src` attribute url to be safe for it to work, hence the error.

This is usually solved with URL encoding, which replaces unsafe ASCII characters with "%" follows by two hexadecimal digits.

```
<img alt="" src="uploads/%23hje-bubble-wrap-factory.jpeg">
```

I hope this helps.